# Redirect preview single post link to a page

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, redirect, previews

I have custom post types setup such that the items don't have or need single-post pages. The posts will be displayed via a custom query on a page.

My question is when i create a single post (on the custom post type), how do i redirect the preview link so it previews the page and not the single-post?

the only way i can think of is make the single-[posttype].php template identical in template and query with the archive page i made, but that just seems wonky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking this question gave me an idea. make the `single-[posttype].php` and inside it just put

```
<?php wp_redirect(get_page_uri(get_page_by_path('your-page-slug')); ?>
```

also works with `get_page_by_title()`

This will direct the preview post and view post link on the admin create post page to the page you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you post type isn't public (doesn't have single view ) or archive (just because you use a custom query) why just not set it as non public?

See [register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function parameters - specially **public** element ?

Comment: if i set it to non-public, will my single-custompost.php template work? if it doesnt then my problem remains, how do i direct the preview link to the archive page?

Comment: if you use a custom query to retrive data from db - yes.

Comment: Tried it, it leaves out the option to preview the post (in the archive page) entirely, which is the goal of my question. But i must say leaving it out entirely just might be another solution to my clients getting confused when making posts and previewing them.